# Python: Split numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have an array produced by numpy which looks as follows:

> [ 54.51399994 -12.10200024 -11.88099957] 
>  [ 56.23899841  -8.30799961 
>   -2.03500009]

How do i convert this to a list? So it looks as follows:

> ['54.51399994','-12.10200024','-11.88099957'] 
>  ['56.23899841','-8.30799961','-2.03500009']

Comment: why do you have quotation in the second ones?  Do you want to convert from number to string?

Comment: Yes, because I'm going to write this out to a text file

Comment: If you are dumping the array to a file, use [np.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt). You do not need to do this conversion yourself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [astype()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy-ndarray-astype) to create a new array of string dtype:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array([
    ( 54.51399994, -12.10200024, -11.88099957),
    ( 56.23899841, -8.30799961, -2.03500009)])
print(arr.astype('|S10'))
```

yields

```
[['54.51399994', '-12.10200024', '-11.88099957'], ['56.23899841', '-8.30799961', '-2.03500009']]
```

Comment: When you print a numpy array, it nicely formats the array without the commas. When you define the array with `np.array`, you have to use commas to separate the items in the tuples. So, yes, the `arr.astype('|S10')` should work on your array.