# Convert python array into list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm confused of converting following `numpy` array

```
[[ 0.  1.  3.  0.  2.  3.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  3.  1.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.  3.  3.  3.  4.]
 [ 0.  1.  3.  0.  2.  3.  1.]
 [ 2.  1.  3.  2.  0.  1.  3.]
 [ 3.  2.  3.  3.  1.  0.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  4.  1.  3.  3.  0.]]
```

in to list of lists as following?

```
([[ 0. , 1. , 3.  ,0. ,2.  ,3.  ,1.],
 [ 1. , 0. , 3. , 1.,  1. , 2. , 2.],
 [ 3.,  3. , 0.,  3. , 3.,  3. , 4.],
 [ 0. , 1. , 3.,  0. , 2. , 3.,  1.],
 [ 2. , 1.,  3. , 2.,  0. , 1.,  3.],
 [ 3. , 2.,  3. , 3. , 1. , 0. , 3.],
 [ 1. , 2.,  4. , 1. , 3.,  3. , 0.]])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979632/python-split-numpy-array?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`tolist()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)

```
x = np.array([[0, 0]]).tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays has [the method `tolist()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2])
>>> a.tolist()
[1, 2]
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> list(a)
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
>>> a.tolist()
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Never thought it is just simple. Thanks.